# Cannot call extension method on base class typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web, typescript2.0

So i have a base class called Report, and then i have another class that extends from Report called Datasheet.

I have wrote an extension for the Report class, and i would like to be able to call it when i have a Datasheet object.

Simple example:

Class wrote in one file

```
export class Report {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Another class wrote in another file

```
export class Datasheet extends Report {
    description: string;
}
```

Here i have wrote a simple extension for the report class, in a different file again

```
import { Report } from './report';

export {};

declare module './report' {
    interface Report {
        hasName(): boolean;
    }
}

Report.prototype.hasName = function() {
    return this.name == null || this.name.length > 0;
};
```

So now i create a new Datasheet and i want to call the extension method `.hasName()`, which compiles fine in typescript, but when it is sent to the browser, i get an error saying

> > m.hasName is not a function

Example, i would to do this (Simple example)

```
const m = new Datasheet();
const check = m.hasName();
```

Why am i getting an error, when this compiles fine?  I am using Typescript 2.4.2.

I am trying to write this, like you can C# objects, and write extension methods. This keeps my objects nice and clean

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't add the `hasName()` method directly to the Report class?

Comment: The code in question works for me when I put everything in a single file without import or declare module. What's the real name of extension method - `hasName` or `hasDescription`?  Is the assignment to `Report.prototype.hasName` executed in the browser before `new Datasheet()` is called?

Comment: In the file you use them do you import the module extension ? I tried and on node it works for me (changed `hasDescription` to `hasName` in the declaration asume it was a typo)

Comment: What causes the extension module to get loaded?

Comment: Not sure why, but i got this working by doing this on the object first         `const report = Object.assign(new Report(), this.report);`
`return report.hasName();`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `prototype` syntax in Typescript, the compiler will create that for you. Preferably, you don't need `Object.assign` either, especially when the problem can be solved with just class syntax.

This shows how you could have a `Datasheet` that extends `Report`, so that you can call `hasName()`.

```
interface IReport { 
    hasName():boolean
}

class Report implements IReport {
    id: number
    name: string
    hasName() { 
      return this.name == null || this.name.length > 0; 
    }
}

class Datasheet extends Report {
    description: string
}

const m = new Datasheet();
const check = m.hasName();
```

Comment: But i dont want to create the function against my object directly

Comment: You won't. If you compile my answer you will see that the javascript is the same as what you wrote in your post: `Report.prototype.hasName = function () {
        return this.name == null || this.name.length > 0;
    };`

Comment: but you have declared the `hasName()` method directly against the `Report` object....

Comment: Yes, but your code does that too... If you don't want hasName to be a method of Report, you have to extend from a class that does. Report extends SomeClass. DataSheet extends Report. But maybe I'm not clear on what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: As i have wrote, i want 2 objects, but i want the methods to be defined somewhere else and not defined against the object, much like having a c# object and writing an extension method somewhere else. This keeps my objects nice and clean, like DTO objects

Comment: There are a couple of discussions about using c# style extension methods in typescript, (it's even a feature request) but they all add the method directly to the object. For example, a `checkdate()` method is added to the existing `Date` object. If what you want is the ability to "wrap" a plain object (a DTO) with some extra functionality, you might want to check out the `@decorator` syntax!